# How can I clean on MySQL a list of Links

Tags: mysql, search, replace

I want to search and replace to clean a list of links, my problem is that I don't know how can I clean this URL:

```
a:1:{s:3:"url";s:55:"https://www.facebook.com/Time-To-Learn-423421174463828/";}
a:1:{s:3:"url";s:27:"http://www.paolaalvarado.do";}
```

I want to cleaned I just want the URL but I don't know what SQL query is need to do it I was going to try with the simple one but I found the links got different numbers in the codes so I don't know how can I replace it

```
update `cta_tasks` set `tsk_address` =
replace(`tsk_address`, 'a:1:{s:3:"url";s:55:"', '');

update `cta_tasks` set `tsk_address` =
replace(`tsk_address`, '";}', '');
```

I was going to try with this but I can't do it like this is not going to work

Comment: Why don't you write a PHP script for that? select -> unserialize -> update

Comment: how can i do that?